# Order by asc is not returning field in order

Tags: mysql, sql

Code:

```
$SQLString = "SELECT DISTINCT NodeNumber, NodeLocation 
              FROM graphnode 
              ORDER BY NodeNumber ASC"
```

Output:

```
1000
1001
1002
101
1010
```

One of my friend is facing this problem and I don't know the complete project details. Any ideas what can be happening here.

Comment: output should have 2 column refer to query but I just see 1 column. Because of copy-paste?

Comment: Looks like a string comparison to me.

Comment: yeah! That was the part causing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your column type is not set to Number Format like Int, it is set to Varchar or some other String Format, you can cast it further and you don't need to give ASC as default order is ASC only not DESC.

Answer (score 10):

the column `NodeNumber` seems to be in string format, convert it to numeric first, example

```
SELECT..
FROM..
WHERE..
ORDER BY CAST(NodeNumber AS SIGNED) ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45130/3)

Comment: @jcho360 so what's the problem now? do you think adding `varchar` with *zero* doesn't `cast` the column into numeric?

Comment: I just added `ORDER BY (NodeNumber+0)`

Comment: @jcho360 it's merely the same :D